# Python: To read files from a folder according to the date as specified on the filename and sort

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have files in a folder which named according to the date and time it recorded: for example: `Test_20150925_181323.data` [Here on the file name `20150925` is the date (2015/09/25) and `181323` is the time (18 hr 13 min 23 sec)]. Likewise I have more than 20 files.

I want to do the following:

1. Read the files according to increasing order of date and time.
2. From each file take the values between lines 11 and 21 (these are values recorded in two columns)
3. Put those values in two arrays say`timevalues=[]` and `yvalues=[]`.
4. Then read the next file do the same and append the values between `line11` and `line12` to `timevalues` and `yvalues`.
5. Finally I should have two arrays, timevalues and yvalues in which the data (between lines 11 and 21 from each file) appended according to the time it recorded.

My attempt:

```
import numpy as np
import re, os
import pandas as pd
from os import walk

path = r'C:\Users\Data1\\'
for data_file in sorted(os.listdir(path)):
    print data_file
times = []
yvals = []

for line in data_file.readlines()[11:21]: # read lines from 11 to 21
    column = line.split('\t')
    times.append(column[0])
    yvals.append(column[1])
    #print times
    #print yvals
```

This is always giving error message:

```
for line in data_file.readlines()[11:21]: # read lines from 11 to 21
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readlines'.
```

Also, I am not sure if this is the right way to read the files according to the time on its filename.

Comment: `data_file` is just the *name* of the file; you need to `open` it, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.listdir()` doesn't return the full paths of files, so you need to join the directory path to each file.

You're trying to `.readlines()` from your filename string.  You need to `open()` the file to use `.readlines()`.

If all your files follow `Test_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.data` format they will sort properly without any `datetime` work needed.

The `fileinput` module makes line counting convenient and handles opening the files sequentially:

```
import os
import fileinput

path = r'C:\Users\Data'
files = [os.path.join(path,data_file) for data_file in sorted(os.listdir(path))]

times = []
yvals = []

f = fileinput.input(files=files)
for line in f:
    if 11 <= f.filelineno() <= 21:
        columns = line.split('\t')
        times.append(column[0])
        yvals.append(column[1])
f.close()
```

Comment: I am getting error message : FileInput instance has no attribute '__exit__'. I tried by adding f.close() at the end, but still getting the same message!

Comment: @Akhil What version of Python?

Comment: @Akhil, I was using Python 3.  It looks like Python 2 doesn't support a context manager interface with `fileinput.input`, which is required to use `with`.  Instead use `f = fileinput.input(files=files)` and `f.close()` at the end.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment which i meant for a previous post. By the way, Here again, I am getting the same error message : FileInput instance has no attribute '__exit__'

Comment: @Akhil Did you remove the `with` statement?  See the current code above.   I only got your error with the original version with `with` and Python 2.7.

Comment: Yes.. i updated.. but now another issue:     yvals.append(column[1])
IndexError: list index out of range  ... The lines between 11 and 21 are just two float numbers spaced with tab in each line. So, it is just two columns of numbers.

Comment: Print out your lines to see what the data looks like before and after a split.  One of the lines didn't split into at least two entries.  You didn't post any sample data, so it is difficult to say.

Comment: Yea.. now it is working.. sorry.. thanks a lot.. May I ask you one more question? How can I add the last value on the column[0] of the first file to the column[0] of the second file. Similarly for all the successive files, add the last value of column[0] of the previous file to the column[0] of each file? This is because each file record time (column[0]) from zero. So by adding the last time one the previous file to each file, I can make the time continuous. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming your `for data_file in sorted(os.listdir(path)):` is working properly. What happens next is the file is opened and within that loop you're going through lines `11:21`.

```
path = r'C:\Users\Data1\\' 
times = []
yvals = []
for data_file in sorted(os.listdir(path)):
    with open(data_file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines()[11:21]: # read lines from 11 to 21
            column = line.split('\t')
            times.append(column[0])
            yvals.append(column[1])
```

Comment: got the error message: with open(data_file, 'r') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Comment: Like I said, your `os.listdir` has to be functional. If it's not finding anything `with open()` won't be executed properly and you'll get the error you mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

def extract_datetime(filename):
    datetime_string = filename.replace('Test_', '')
    datetime_string = datetime_string.replace('.data', '')
    return datetime.strptime(datetime_string, '%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')

# Sort files by date/time
log_files = os.listdir(path)
log_files.sort(key=extract_datetime)

for f in log_files:
    with open(f, 'r') as infile:
        lines = infile.readlines()[11:21]
        # The rest of your original code here
```

Comment: got the error message:  return datetime_string.strptime(datetime_string, '%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strptime'

Comment: I didn't mention that you have to import datetime.datetime for this.  Although it sounds like you already have a `datetime` variable holding a string, which is why it's complaining.  I'm guessing there's a bunch of other code that you didn't post?

Comment: Now another error message:  with open(f, 'r') as infile:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Test_20150925_181323.data'.